# What is the value of $E(X)$ of the random varaible $X(w) = a_1$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Supouse that an randon experiment consist on picking a random number from the $(0, 1)$ interval. Each result $w$ is given by $w = 0.a_1a_2...$ where $a_i \in \{0,1,2,...,9\}$,  $ i = 1, 2,...\qquad$Considering the probablity space by $$(\Omega = (0, 1),\textit{ f } = B((0,1)), P = \lambda)$$ Where $\lambda$ is a probablity measure given by $\lambda((a,b)) = b - a \quad$ for every interval $(a,b)$ at $(0,1)$

What is the value of $E(X)$ of the random varaible $X(w) = a_1$?

Well I know that in order to get $E(X)$  I got to find the probability function $f_X(x)$. I know that the random variable $X$ takes any $w \in (0,1)$ and takes it to a single point on the real set. My trouble comes when I got to define the probability function because I dont get how $\lambda((a,b)) = b-a$ is apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ can only take on finitely many values, $E(X)$ is given by:
$$E(X)= 0\cdot P(X=0)+1\cdot P(X=1)+\cdots+9\cdot P(X=9).$$
Now for each $k \in \{0,1,\dots,9\}$,
$$P(X=k) = P(X(\omega)=k) = P(\{\omega \mid X(\omega)=k\}).$$
Now you need to describe the set of $\omega$ for which $X(\omega)=k$, and  use the definition of $P=\lambda$ to calculate $P(\{\omega \mid X(\omega)=k\})$.