# Which of the following are random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Consider a radom experiment with result spaces $\Omega = (0,1)$ and $\sigma$-algebra

$\mathbf{f} = \{(0,1),(0,\frac{1}{2}), [\frac{1}{2},1), \emptyset\}$

Which of the following are random variables?

(a)$X(w) = \mathbf{1}_{[\frac{1}{2}, 1]}(w)$

(b)$X(w) = \mathbf{1}_{[\frac{1}{3}, 1]}(w)$

(c)$X(w) = 2*\mathbf{1}_{(0, \frac{1}{2})}(w) + 3*\mathbf{1}_{[\frac{1}{2}, 1)}(w)$

We got to look if this is true $X^{-1}(\{x\}) \in \mathbf{f}$

for (a) we got that $X^{-1}(\{x\}) = [\frac{1}{2}, 1) \in \mathbf{f}$

for (b) we got that $X^{-1}(\{x\}) = [\frac{1}{3}, 1) \notin \mathbf{f}$

Well I  don´t know if these two answers are correct. And for part (c) I dont get how multipliying by scalars works on these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to check $X^{-1}(B) \in \mathbf{f}$ for every Borel subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

For (a) there are four cases. If $1 \in B$ and $0 \notin B$, then $X^{-1}(B)=[\frac{1}{2},1) \in \mathbf{f}$. If $0 \in B$ and $1 \notin B$, then $X^{-1}(B) = (0,\frac{1}{2})\in \mathbf{f}$. If $1 \in B$ and $0 \in B$, then $X^{-1}(B)=(0,1) \in \mathbf{f}$. Finally, if $1 \notin B$ and $0 \notin B$, then $X^{-1}(B) = \emptyset \in \mathbf{f}$.

You should check the same cases for (b).

For (d), you could check a bunch of cases depending on whether whether $0$, $1$, and/or $2$ are in $B$. However, you can also use the fact that linear combinations of random variables are random variables. So it's enough to check that $mathbf{1}_{(0,\frac{1}{2})}(x)$ and $\mathbf{1}_{[\frac{1}{2},1)}(x)$ are measurable with respect to $\mathbf{f}$.

Comment: Thanks kccu. Makes a lot more sense now! What do you think about this one? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3449137/what-is-the-value-of-ex-of-the-random-varaible-xw-a-1